# How to change default styles of ion-select in ionic 4 ( .select-placeholder,.select-icon..etc . elements under the #shadow-root)

Tags: ionic4, ion-select

I am new to ionic. I am Stuck with ion-select styling, How can I change default styles of ion-select in ionic 4? I'm not able to change it by overwriting CSS.

like this

```
.select-placeholder {
    color: black;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: ionic 4 components can styled only through the css variables they provide..

Comment: @SurajRao yes, but in the case of #shadow-root elements like .select-placeholder under the ion-select, I didn't find any CSS variables to set the opacity and also am unable to adjust the down-arrow button.                                                                         eg: This .select-text is a #shadow-root element and there is no CSS variables                `.select-text {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    min-width: 16px;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}`

Comment: Unless ionic devs have used css 4 variables to set that style, you cant use it... You might want to read up on web components

Comment: @SurajRao : Okay , Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Specting Html and you will find the "part" of ion-select, after that just css follow that "part".

[image]

```
ion-select::part(placeholder) {
    color: blue;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it,

```
window.customElements.whenDefined("ion-select").then(() => {
    let selectPlaceholder = document.querySelector("ion-select").shadowRoot.querySelector(".select-placeholder");
    selectPlaceholder.style.setProperty("color", "black");
    selectPlaceholder.style.setProperty("opacity", "1");
});
```

Comment: where do I inject this? When I add it the the .ts file on the component, it breaks.

Comment: @riotgear try appending `window.` before `customElements`. I have updated the answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
.select-ios .select-placeholder{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

an unorthodox method but it was useful for me to change a js file after compiling:
\ node_modules \ @ionic \ core \ dist \ esm \ es5 \ build \ j241fzpw.entry.js

select-placeholder {color: currentColor; opacity: 0.33}

for

select-placeholder {color: currentColor; opacity: 1}

I'm not sure but maybe the file in question could vary

Comment: Modifying the contents of node_modules is not a reliable fix for many, many reasons.

Comment: This is not a robust solution given that it will only work locally and be overwrote when you run a "npm install". Also team members wont have access to this - unless you were to create a fork, which is not ideal for such a change.